# Managing MSTest Test List & Test Result columns

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mstest

MSTest provides a default set of columns to display for the *Test List Editor* and *Test Results* windows.  I find that I'm constantly adding the same columns over and over again in different branches and workspaces.

Is there anyway that I can configure these columns for all developers in my team?

Comment: I've also got this problem, in our case because of our desire to use MbUnit tests but the MSTest IDE runner.